# Using SSL on main domain in WHM

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cpanel, whm

I have one domain hosted on my memset virtual server running WHM/Cpanel. Although I do want to access the features of cPanel I don't want my domain to act like it is on a shared IP address as this doesn't allow me to install a SSL certificate on it.

I can install a shared SSL but this is not what i need. e.g. I can get  https://mydomain.co.uk/~user/ to work but not https://mydomain.co.uk/

Is there any way to make my domain a "main" domain so that I don't have to purchase another IP address as I am only hosting one site on this account.

Thanks in advance

Grant

Answer (score 0):

The Activate SSL on Your Website interface is only present when your domain has a dedicated IP address. So you can't use server IP for SSL you need at least one dedicated IP if you have only domain.